# C Programming. How to make method to print a string

Tags: c, string

I am trying to make a function in C that will print a string taken as a parameter.  Is this even possible in C?

I have something like this in my header file, but string is not a valid identifier. I understand there are no strings in C, but what's the string.h class for?

```
#include <string.h>    

#ifndef _NEWMAIN_H
#define _NEWMAIN_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void print (string message){  //this is where i need help
        printf("%s", message);
    }


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* _NEWMAIN_H */
```

Comment: thank you all. i learned something new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, there is no native `string` type.

C handles strings as a null-terminated `char` array.

For example:

```
char* string = "this is a string";
```

The [`string.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String.h) exists to perform string manipulation functions on C strings, which are of type `char*`.

When printing a string using [`printf`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf), one would pass in a variable of `char*`:

```
char* string_to_print = "Hello";
printf("%s", string_to_print);
```

For more information on strings in C, the [Wikipedia page on C strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string) would be a good start.

Comment: I think most C compilers let you get away with non-const pointers to string literals, but "this is a string" really is const and should be pointed at by a const char *.

Answer (score 3):

```
void print (const char* message) {
            printf("%s", message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it briefly, for your homework assignment, which is to replace printf, you will want to use `char *` as pointed out by others, and use fwrite to stdout.

For a related question you can look at 
[C/C++ best way to send a number of bytes to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528559/c-c-best-way-to-send-a-number-of-bytes-to-stdout)

Answer (score 0):

There are no strings in C, since there are no classes in C.  [string.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/) provides the routines for handling string text manipulation in C, using pointers to char.

You'll want to rewrite this like:

```
void print(const char* message) {
    printf(message); // You don't need the formatting, since you're only passing through the string
}
```

That being said, it's not really any different than just calling printf directly.

Comment: You should always use formating even if its just "%s".  If the string you are printing is "%s" you've got a problem.

Comment: @Craig Only if you print strings from unreliable source (such as user or external), however printing your own strings without format is safe. Dogmas are bad - you need to know WHY.